# How to Configure the PCSCD for SmartCard

Tags: macos, driver, smartcard, dylib, pcsc

i am newbee in the PCSC driver development and i have a Mac OSX 10.8.4 (mountain lion) which has PCSC Framework version 1.4.0.

I have a smart card and i have library or c code using which i am able to read and write to card (i.e get ATR etc.)

I would like to know the procedure to configure PCSC so that the smart card is recognized by PCSCD

I tried to make a dylib (dynamic library) of the c code that communicates with the card and created made an entry in the /etc/reader.conf and placed the dylib in the path specified.
But i was still unable to get any repsonce (i.e get ATR) when i did pcscd -afd.

any suggestion or links would be helpful